# Связь сервера с телефоном

Tags: android, сервер, spring-boot

Пишу приложение под андроид типа месенджера. На данном этапе телефон сам отправляет запросы на сервер каждые 10 секунд для проверки новых сообщений. Знаю, что это не правильно. Как реализовать систему, в которой сервер сам отправляет телефону новые сообщения? Клиент на андроиде, сервер пишу на spring-boot. Спасибо за инфу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно соединение по сокетам. Пока оно работает - клиенты смогут сразу получать сообщения.

Однако поддержание постоянного соединения потребует запускать Foreground сервис, который будет люто раздражать юзеров, т.к. это будет неубираемое, постоянно висящее в шторке уведомление.

Чтобы юзера ничего не раздражало - используйте FCM - он делает тоже самое - держит постоянное соединение с сервером по сокетам, но, в отличие от вашего приложения, гугловым приложениям можно нарушать правила, установленные самим же гуглом - уведомления в шторке не будет.